# Check if today's date falls between two future dates and update a field accordingly

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I want to update a field if today's date falls between two future dates as input by user. I think we need to use time-based workflows, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Time-dependent action does require either a time-based workflow (WFR or Process Builder) or the use of Scheduled Apex running on an interval.

Your requirement appears to be easily met by the use of scheduled actions in Process Builder. You can set actions to fire 0 days after your user-input start date, based upon a record change. If you need to perform an additional update following the end date, you can do the same process for that field.

If you need actions to take place at, for example, midnight every night to locate and update records whose dates include that day, you would be looking at a Scheduled Apex solution.

Comment: Okay i did as u said i have done time dependent action, I kept the action as 0 days after Start Date and also 0 days after End date. What if i kept Start Date as yesterday and End date as tomorrow will that work? I can see two time dependent actions created in my Workflow but cannot see update in my field.

Comment: Scheduled actions that are set to execute at a date in the past should execute immediately.